# An error cannot convert from 'void *' to 'float *' `

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I write a c++ function and its associated mex. But the one kind of input of c++ function is `double *`.

1. The output of function `pointwise_search` is a pointer. I was told that I should delete it. But I do not know where I should delete it since I need it as an output.
2. From the answer, I know I should check the type of input by `mxIsSingle`. So I correct the function `mexFunction`. But there is an error `error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'float *'`.
3. In matlab, I should call like `pointwise_search(`float *p`,`float *q`, num_thres,`float* n`, len )`. If I have a vector v_in_matlab=rand(5,1) in matlab. I should I get it pointer by `p=single(v_in_matlab);` and then `pointwise_search(p...`

Thanks in advance.

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


float * pointwise_search(float *p,float *q,int num_thres, float* n, int len )
{
    vector<float> P(p, p + num_thres);
    vector<float> Q(q, q + num_thres);
    int size_of_threshold = P.size();
    float  *Y=new float[len];
    float *z=new float[len];
    typedef vector<float > ::iterator IntVectorIt ;
    IntVectorIt start, end, it, location ;
    start = P.begin() ;   // location of first
    // element of Numbers

    end = P.end() ;       // one past the location
    // last element of Numbers

    for (int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        location=lower_bound(start, end, n[i]) ;
        z[i]=location - start;
        if(z[i]>0&&z[i]<size_of_threshold)
        {

            Y[i]=(n[i]-P[z[i]])/(P[z[i]-1]-P[z[i]])*(Q[z[i]-1]-Q[z[i]])+Q[z[i]];
        }
        else
        {
            Y[i]=Q[z[i]];
        }
    }

    return (&Y[0]);
}




 void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
   {
    float * Numbers, *Q;
    if (nrhs != 5)
    {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Input is wrong!");
    }
    float *n = (float*) mxGetData(prhs[3]);
    int len = (int) mxGetScalar(prhs[4]);
    int num_thres = (int) mxGetScalar(prhs[2]);

    /* Input gs */

    if(mxIsComplex(prhs[0])
    ||!mxIsSingle(prhs[0]))
        mexErrMsgTxt("Input 0 should be a class Single");
    /* get the pointer to gs */
    Numbers=mxGetData(prhs[0]);


    if(mxIsComplex(prhs[0])
    ||!mxIsSingle(prhs[0]))
        mexErrMsgTxt("Input 0 should be a class Single");
    /* get the pointer to gs */
    Q=mxGetData(prhs[1]);

//     float * Numbers= (float *)mxGetData(prhs[0]);
//     float * Q= (float *)mxGetData(prhs[1]);

    float * out= pointwise_search(Numbers,Q,num_thres,n,len );
    //float* resizedDims = (float*)mxGetPr(out);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab use `single()` to convert the data before calling the mexFunction. On the C++ side verify that the type is indeed single by `mxIsSingle()`. After this you can happily cast to `float*`.

Answer (score 1):

Before you worry about your MEX code, have another look at your C++ function first.  You have some really obvious [memory leaks](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++MemoryCorruptionAndMemoryLeaks.html) (`new` but no `delete[]`).

Regarding MEX you should never see this:

```
(float *)mxGetPr(prhs[0])
```

You can't cast a `double*` to a `float*` and expect the numbers to make any sense.  Input `single` from MATLAB and use:

```
(float *)mxGetData(prhs[0])
```

And do as Trilarion suggests and test all of your input `mxArray`s for the expected data type.

Comment: thank you for your comment. Could you tell me where I should delete the output `Y` of the function `pointwise_search`